# Android: Check if MySQL timestamp is today or yesterday ELSE output formatted timestamp

Tags: android, mysql

so I am getting timestamp from MySQL database which is in following format: 2014-12-09 16:46:26

I want before applying that Date to TextView - to check if date is today or yesterday.
Basically like:

```
if(timestamp == today){
TextView = "Today";
}
else if(timestamp == yesterday){
TextView = "Yesterday";
}
else{
TextView = FormatTimeStamp(DD/MM/YY hh:mm);
}
```

I was writing this code:

```
String dats = timestamp; //2014-12-09 16:46:26
String[] datsdt = dats.split("\\s+");
String[] dateSplit = datsdt[0].split("\\-");
String[] timeSplit = datsdt[1].split("\\:");
int year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DATE);
```

Then compare split date parts with current year month and day, but that seems way too long and I am sure it's wrong way of doing it.

So how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat to parse the Date and Calendar to compare the dates.:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    Date date = sdf.parse("2014-12-09 16:46:26");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(date);
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
    Calendar yesterday = Calendar.getInstance();
    yesterday.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
    yesterday.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

    if (c.getTime().equals(new Date())){
        //TODAY
    } else if (c.equals(yesterday)) {
        //yesterday
    } else {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
        TextView  = sdf1.format(date);
    }
```